# How do I grant SeBatchLogon privileges to a domain account on a Windows server with Powershell?

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server

I am using Windows Server 2008 R2.  For a server joined onto a Windows 2008 R2 domain I want to grant SeBatchLogon privileges to an account, for example, I want the domain account 'mydomain\batchuser' to have batch logon privileges on the local Windows 2008R2 server so that I can run scheduled tasks under that logon.  I can set the privileges through the Windows GUI, but how can I script this with Powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ntrights.exe`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315276) from the [Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17657):

```
ntrights +r SeBatchLogon -u mydomain\batchuser
```

Comment: I looked into that, but we do not have the resource kit installed.  I'll have to check with our administrators to see if this is a possibility.  I was hoping there was something native to Windows that I could use.

Comment: You can download the package and extract that executable. It runs by itself, no installation required.